# How to use database procedure in fluent nhibernate mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, firebird

I have this class

```
public class Bill : EntityBase
{
      public virtual decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

and in below mapping, I fill in the value of 'Value' using a procedure in a `Formula()`

```
public class MapBill : ClassMap<Bill>
{
    public MapBill()
    {
        Table("cabrec");
        Map(m => m.Value)
            .Formula(
"(select t.VALOR_IND from ret_vlorind(1,1,cast('02/06/1993' as Date)) as t)")
            .CustomType(typeof(decimal));
    }
}
```

But it returns the error when executing:

```
{"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -104\r\nToken unknown - line 1, column 279\r\n."}
```

Is there any way to use procedure in fluent nhibernate?

Comment: Which kind of Db are you using. Maybe this could solve your problem http://www.iprogrammable.com/2009/09/05/get-oracle-stored-procedure-output-object-output-in-nhibernate/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had tried this way but to no avail. The problem is in the 'alias' of the procedure. using Firebird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula mapping expression is later converted by NHibernate to statement like this

```
// source in code
(select t.VALOR_IND from ret_vlorind(1,1,cast('02/06/1993' as Date)) as t)
// sent SQL statement
(select t.VALOR_IND from ret_vlorind(1,1,cast('02/06/1993' as Date)) as this_.t)
```

The **this_.** prefix is injected at places, where NHibernate thinks it should properly use MAIN table alias.

This is not what we want.. and the only way I found, is to introduce our own Dialect (I am working with SQL Server) and define some "CONSTANTS" to be treated as - **I do not need prefix**

```
public class CustomMsSql2012Dialect : MsSql2012Dialect
{
    public CustomMsSql2012Dialect()
    {
        RegisterKeyword("my_table_alias");
        ...
```

This must be used for configuration

```
<property name="dialect">MyNamespace.CustomMsSql2012Dialect,MyLib</property>
```

And finally, we have to adjust our statement

```
// wrong t is not known keyword.. would be prefixed
(select t.VALOR_IND from ret_vlorind(1,1,cast('02/06/1993' as Date)) as t)
// into this
(select my_table_alias.VALOR_IND from ret_vlorind(1,1,cast('02/06/1993' as Date)) as my_table_alias)
```

*NOTE: keywords, my experience, must be just lower case*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Fluent Nhibernate. I gotta understand the problem, but I'm new to 'Fluent' and I do not know where I can create this alias, do you know if you can create this using 'Fluent'?

Comment: Well, the only change (in fluent) would be the way how dialect is set. Check this http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/09/06/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-4-configuration.html. `An example var cfg = new MyConfiguration()    .ShowSql()

    .Driver<SQLite20Driver>()

    .Dialect<CustomMsSql2012Dialect>()`

Comment: Shouldn't the `t.VALOR_IND` be changed to `my_table_alias.VALOR_IND`? In the case of the OP, its base dialect would be `FirebirdDialect`. Yes keywords are to be registered in lower case. A bit unfortunate it is not adjusted by `RegisterKeyword` itself, but so is it currently. They will match any case in queries though, provided they were registered in lower case. (Candidate tokens are "lowercased" before matching.)

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED !! thank you very much Radim Köhler and Frédéric. Thanks to you I was able to solve the problem.